# Security in Database Connection

Tags: php, mysqli

Yesterday I made my first php script that connects to a db and, with some help from SO, it now works!
This script is running on my localhost. I'd like to now add the script to the live site but I'm concerned about security. The site in question is a PHP based CMS. Within this CMS there is a script called "detail.php" that is used to generate content on particular pages. The script I made yesterday appears within this content so I just added my mysqli (called "get_vote_date.php") script to the same directory as detail.php thus

```
<?php
                        include("get_vote_date.php")  
                        ?>
```

Here is what the script looks like:

```
<?php # script get_vote_date

// This file contains the db info
// This file establishes a mysql connection, connects to the db and then gets the most recent vote date for a particular page (incident_id).

DEFINE ('DB_USER','myname');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD','pass123');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST','localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME','local_sitename');


// make the db connection
$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME)
    OR die ('Could not connect to mysql: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

// Set the encoding
mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');

// set the query variable
$query = "SELECT MAX(rating_date) 
          AS last_date
          FROM rating
          WHERE incident_id = $incident_id;";

//connect and run the query
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

 echo $result->fetch_object()->last_date;

?>
```

As you can see there is sensitive information here - the db connection data. If I just add the script as is is that enough? I'm not trying to go beyond reasonable precaution here, my goal is to add the script with reasonable security only.

I did notice that in the config file there is a database.php file which appears to hold the connection data too:

```
$config['default'] = array(
    'benchmark' => TRUE,
    'persistent' => FALSE,
    'connection' => array(
        'type' => 'mysqli',
        'user' => 'myname',
        'pass' => 'somepass123',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => FALSE,
        'socket' => FALSE,
        'database' => 'local_sitename',
    ),
    'character_set' => 'utf8',
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'object' => TRUE,
    'cache' => FALSE,
    'escape' => TRUE
);
```

My intuition tells me that it would be more secure to call these variables rather than include them in the script. Is that right? I'm new to PHP and would even have to research how to select the variables in the array here. For example, what would be the syntax to call  'pass' above? If this is even the best thing to do?

Should I leave the script as is or should I call the connection details contained within the config/database.php file? Am I missing any other important security considerations?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking if it's safer to have the database connection info in `detail.php`, as opposed to have it in `get_vote_date.php` and then include it in `detail.php`?

Comment: @goddfree no I'm asking if it's OK to leave the db connection details in get_vote_date.php (which is called by details.php) or if I should call the connection variables that appear to already exist in the config files. My intuition tells me that the config files would be best practice - is it? Is it more secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security-wise, it shouldn't make a different where this information is stored. As long as PHP is working properly (meaning it's actually being executed as opposed to being displayed as plain text), then your information should be secure (unless, of course, another user has access to the server itself).

Essentially, with a properly configured server no one should be able to get access to your PHP source code, and thus no one should be able to get your database credentials from that source code. If somehow a malicious user does get access to your web server, then it won't make a difference where this data is stored.

The question here, I think, is more-so one of efficiency rather than security. I have personally always stored my database credentials in one file, and then included that file in all other files that interact with my MySQL databases (usually I call it `db.php`). In the event that my database credentials change, it will be very easy for me to simply edit `db.php`, rather than going all through my files and changing the credentials every time they were listed. The end result is still the same.

So to answer your question, I would include the `database.php` file and use the database credentials from the `$config` array. Your CMS most likely uses the same method I mentioned above, which is why (I'm assuming) you only entered your database credentials once in `database.php`, and this file is included in all other CMS files that interact with the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I "felt" that that was right (using the database.php file in config folder) but could not identify why :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider for some extra security is using an htaccess file to redirect all requests to a certain directory. This is helpful especially in shared hosting environments. Say you want all your traffic to go to your "application" folder. Then, in your web-root, you make a folder "application", and you place an .htaccess file in your web-root alongside the application folder with the code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    application/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) application/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is a pretty common technique in a lot of PHP frameworks. You store your sensitive files above the application directory, and all traffic from the outside gets redirected to the application directory.